# Python 'for' loop performance too slow

Tags: python, loops

I have over 500,000 rows in my dataframe and a number of similar 'for' loops which are causing my code to take over a hour to complete its computation. Is there a more efficient way of writing the following 'for' loop so that things run a lot faster:

```
col_26 = []
col_27 = []
col_28 = []


for ind in df.index:
    if df['A_factor'][ind] > df['B_factor'][ind]:
        col_26.append('Yes')
        col_27.append('No')
        col_28.append(df['A_value'][ind])
    elif df['A_factor'][ind] < df['B_factor'][ind]:
        col_26.append('No')
        col_27.append('Yes')
        col_28.append(df['B_value'][ind])
    else:
        col_26.append('')
        col_27.append('')
        col_28.append(float('nan'))
```

Comment: A `for` loop of 500,000 items runs in less than a second. So it not the `for` loop that causes the trouble.

Comment: Likely things will be monumentally faster if done in Pandas or NumPy...

Comment: Use column operations.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  More code? You might be using a ton of memory if you are creating  many 500,000 length lists and that creates the slow down and it's not a cpu problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the pandas iterrows() function or using apply, you can look at this article aswell: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

Answer (score 1):

Try column operations:

```
data = {'A_factor': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'A_value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
           'B_factor': [2, 3, 1, 2, 6],
        'B_value': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['col_26'] = ''
df['col_27'] = ''
df['col_28'] = np.nan

mask = df['A_factor'] > df['B_factor']
df.loc[mask, 'col_26'] = 'Yes'
df.loc[~mask, 'col_26'] = 'No'
df.loc[mask, 'col_28'] = df[mask]['A_value']

df.loc[~mask, 'col_27'] = 'Yes'
df.loc[mask, 'col_27'] = 'No'
df.loc[~mask, 'col_28'] = df[~mask]['B_value']
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending to lists in Python is painfully slow. Initializing the lists before the iteration can speed things up. For example,

```
def f():
    x = []
    for ii in range(500000):
        x.append(str(x))

def f2():
    x = [""] * 500000
    for ii in range(500000):
        x[ii] = str(x)


timeit.timeit("f()", "from __main__ import f", number=10)
# Output: 1.6317970999989484
timeit.timeit("f2()", "from __main__ import f2", number=10)
# Output: 1.3037318000024243
```

Since you're already using pandas / numpy, there are ways to vectorize your operations so they don't need looping. For example:

```
a_factor = df["A_factor"].to_numpy()
b_factor = df["B_factor"].to_numpy()

col_26 = np.empty(a_factor.shape, dtype='U3') # U3 => string of size 3
col_27 = np.empty(a_factor.shape, dtype='U3')
col_28 = np.empty(a_factor.shape)

a_greater = a_factor > b_factor
b_greater = a_factor < b_factor
both_equal = a_factor == b_factor

col_26[a_greater] = 'Yes'
col_26[b_greater] = 'No'

col_27[a_greater] = 'Yes'
col_27[b_greater] = 'No'

col_28[a_greater] = a_factor[a_greater]
col_28[b_greater] = b_factor[b_greater]
col_28[both_equal] = np.nan
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to provide that example. I shall also look at vectorization, I am very new to this, but here to learn. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`append` causes python requests for heap memory to get more memory. using `append` in `for` loop causes get memory and free it continually to get more memory. so it's better to say to python how many item you need.

```
col_26 = [True]*500000
col_27 = [False]*500000
col_28 = [float('nan')]*500000

for ind in df.index:
    if df['A_factor'][ind] > df['B_factor'][ind]:
        col_28[ind] = df['A_value'][ind]
    elif df['A_factor'][ind] < df['B_factor'][ind]:
        col_26[ind] = False
        col_27[ind] = True
        col_28[ind] = df['B_value'][ind]
    else:
        col_26[ind] = ''
        col_27[ind] = ''
```